# Mains Power Metering

Tags: current, amplifier, current-measurement, mains

please see this schematics:

[image]

Please look at the 3 transformers to the right of the picture (above the houses). They are current transformers.

On the other hand, we have an SGM30C2 electrical meter. (below in the picture). That equipment receives the input voltage (380 VAC, the wider vertical line in the picture) and the 3 lines coming from the current transformer.

Well... the problem is that the current that enters into the measure equipment is about some milliamperes, however, the equipment can measure only if current is above 5 A, so I need to amplify that current.

What circuit design do you recommend for this case? I am electronical engineer and I have designed a simple current amplifier based on an OPAMP and a MOSFET (similar to the following picture), however, I need to know your opinions about this.

[image: Simple amplifier]

An ideal current amplifier should have a very low input impedance and very high output impedance, however, by using an OPAMP, this is the contrary.

Other point to note is that this is a triphasic circuit, so that, each AC current line has a shift of 120° and the frequency is 50 Hz.

Any hint, please?

Thanks

EDIT:

The houses are being fed directly. The fact is that we need to measure power consumption. The measure equipment is doing that, measuring the consumption, in kW-H, of the houses.

The transformers are like this one:

[image: Open core-coil transformer]

The advantage of this transformer is that it is not necessary to open the line in order to measure current. When current passes through the transformer, other current is inducted in the lines that go to the measure equipment.

EDIT:

[image: CT electrical parameters]

Comment: A bipolar transistor is a current amplifier.  Have you looked into using those?

Comment: So why aren't you feeding the houses through the meter, and not using the current transformers at all?

Comment: What value burden resistor is applied to your current transformers? Where are they placed in your "schematic"?

Comment: @SimonB I have edited the question. Please check which transformer we are using. Imagine this is a domiciliary network. We need to measure power consumption of the houses in an already build network. By the way, this schema works in a city, where currents are above 5 A, but this same schema is installed in a field where current is about 60 mA. in that case, the measure equipment cannot measure.

Comment: @Andyaka there is not burden resistor. Please see the question again, because I have edited. Also, please read my comment above,

Comment: Regards the CT, no data sheet = no help. Pictures of something that looks like what you use is of no interest.

Comment: Trying to amplify the current coming out of your CTs is the wrong way to approach this (and the circuit you're proposing won't work for AC). Why are you not simply replacing the CTs with ones with a smaller ratio such that they produce a higher output current?

Comment: The current from the CTs needs to be shunted through resistors or you will have problems. You can measure the voltage across these resistors.

Comment: @brhans That is not an option since they already have the CT's. They also already have the measure equipments.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy That is not the option. The lines should go to the existing measurement equipment. Those measurment equipments are connected to 4G modems in order to get consumption remotely

Comment: @Andyaka I don't understand you. Why do you need the datasheet? I think there is of no importance for the problem. I am only looking for a AC current ampifier. What about this? https://bit.ly/2LNfoRK

Comment: If you understood me then you'd understand why I asked for the data sheet.

Comment: Your diagram is too small to see the details. Please upload a larger (higher resolution) image.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I added a new larger image. Please consider that those are the existing elements so I cannot change any of them. The only thing I can do is to place a circuit between the current transformer ("Transformador de corriente" in the picture) and the measure equipment ("Equipo de medida" in the picture). I know about the existence of AC current amplifiers when talking about audio pre-amplification so I think this is possible. Thanks.

Comment: Those current transducers look like the type with built-in burden resistors that are designed to output a voltage rather than a current. Again, without a datasheet we're all just guessing. The solution will depend on knowing.

Comment: @Andyaka I have uploaded electrical parameters of the CT from the document description, if you consider it is useful. It is in Spanish but I think you can understand the values since they are standard.

Comment: @Transistor I have uploaded electrical parameters. Model is  SCTK667H‐036 and the whole description document does not mention what you say, but I believe you.However, document says this: "A high precision internal resistance
installed across the secondary winding of CT provides safe levels of current or voltage.
Reduce installation costs and man hours".I don't think this is what you are referring to.

Comment: No, I'd need a data sheet link. Doesn't matter if it's in Spanish.

Comment: **The advantage of this transformer is that it is not necessary to open the line in order to measure current.**  That is the aspect of any current transformer.  You have a current sensor not compatible with your current transformer.  You are going to have to jump through a lot of hoops to make this work.  Then you have to calibrate it.  Figure out your load current.  Then select the correct current transformer.

Comment: I am suggesting we close this question, as information necessary for solving the problem has not been provided.

Answer (score 2):

The meter you are using is a SGM30C2. The question, as I see it, is how to meter the aggregate current of multiple houses using this meter. The maximum total current that the houses may use is, at the moment, unknown.

Since the metering is intended for the purposes of technical monitoring, rather than billing customers, there is greater legal flexibility for the solution.

According to the [SGM3000 series User Manual](https://www.dias.cl/Aclara%20-%20GEH7111_SGM3000_User_Manual.pdf), the SGM30C2 is a "three element CT connect meter" (p20) which handles a max current of 5A (p18). It perhaps needs to be verified before things get too far, but my assumption at this point is that the SGM30C2 takes as input the output current of a 5A Current Transformer. (5A Current Transformers are one of the standard types available).

Given the assumption above, the main requirement to determine is the proper turns ratio and ampere-turns capacity to generate a 0-5A signal from whatever current is flowing to the houses.

The turns ratio should be

$$N=\frac{I_{load}}{5A}$$

Once that is determined, finding a source and/or building an appropriate current transformer can be accomplished.

Another assumption that I am working with, is that the current to be measured will be the 380VAC described, and not the higher voltage (but lower current) power that feeds the utility pole transformers. (I am assuming a system similar to that in the United States).

If that assumption is correct, then the maximum current you would need to monitor is the maximum current of the consumer side of the utility pole transformers. (Perhaps you can 1. validate my assumption, and 2. obtain the rating for the utility pole transformers).

In the absence of such data, my recommendation would be to buy a set of the highest rated 5A Current Transformers that you believe you may need.
The 600A:5A Current Transformer at the bottom of your chart may be sufficient. I don't know.

If the actual current is larger than the rated current of the CT, it is likely that the core of the CT will saturate. For power transformers, core saturation can be disastrous due to the high currents that may arise. However, for a current transformer, the result will be a distorted waveform, with output current not expected to be much over the rated output current. This distorted output will be part of a sign that the CT is under-rated, and the metering is consequently inaccurate. However, the loads in the households may also distort the current waveform.

---

You wrote:

> Well... the problem is that the current that enters into the measure equipment is about some milliamperes, however, the equipment can measure only if current is above 5 A, so I need to amplify that current.

If you choose a current transformer with a 0-5A output, it should work with the meter you have installed. The meter does not require a current above 5A, but a current from 0 to 5A.

---

If you *must* use those particular CTs, and you *must* use those particular current sensors, and the two do not match, (the current is too small) and your only option is to add some components in between, you could insert transformers to step up the current. (The same kind of transformers as step down voltage).

However, the exact same result could be achieved by using CTs with fewer turns in the secondary.

Comment: Hello.... I have thought about placing CT's between the original CT's and the sensor (remember, I cannot do anything with the CT's already existing in the line). However, I can build and test electronical components. I have all the elements like oscilloscpe, multimeter, protoboard, etc. since I am electronical engineer, but I have lost practice in electronics design so even when I could do that by myself, some advice will be greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: On the other hand, I have never worked with CT's so if you know how to choose the right one, can you tell me? should I request someone to manufacture one? or there is some in the marketplace? Returning to current amplifier, what do you think about this one? https://cutt.ly/4jQwY7r

Comment: There are many CT available commercially, although it is possible to create one yourself. To know what CT you should use, we need to know the circuit or device that the CT feeds. You say that it measures current, and that it is already installed, and you say that the current from your CT is too small, but we need _numbers_ or better yet, a datasheet for that circuit/device. It is quite possible that one of the SCTK667H-036s will work without any modifications. But we don't have the data to choose one.

Comment: As for your question about a current amplifier, a) it is unlikely (but remotely possible) that what you need is an op-amp amplifier. But, b) even if that were the case, the basic problem is that you cannot choose the right components without knowing what you are trying to achieve _with numbers_. Provide the details of the circuit that measures the current from your CTs. Provide a data sheet, a schematic, a part number, specifications, _something_, or there is no way other than trial and error to actually design something that properly interfaces with it.

Comment: Hello.... all informatoon in in PDF format.... I can upload them to my server but I don't know if StackExchange will have a problem with that.... or, if it provides a repository where to upload this kind of information, it will be better. Can I upload somewhere?

Comment: Currently, they have CT with ratios 10/10mA, 50/25mA, etc... but they need 10/5, 15/5, 20/5, etc, since 5 A is the sensitivity range of the sensor. So at present, one should think that as the sensor input will have milliamperes (in some cases, 10mA, and other installations 25mA, other 60 mA, etc...)... in any case all currents are below 1A. It is also possible to install more than one amplifier in series to get the desired gain if with only one is not enough and if there is no possible to use a potentiometer to adjust the gain. I will upload the sensor datasheet later to some server.

Comment: Hello... I have uploaded sensor user manual at https://bit.ly/39C50EK. The CT is at https://bit.ly/39we129 (in Spanish but you will find technical parameters)

Comment: Thank-you. Which model of the SGM3000 meter do you have installed? Pages 17-20 of the manual list 8 variants.

Comment: Also, are you metering for collecting revenue? Will people pay based upon the meter reading? Or is this for technical monitoring of mains power? If for collecting revenue, there may be (probably) legal requirements imposed upon the metering. Another question, what is the maximum current that all of the houses combined might draw? That is, what is the maximum current your meter needs to be able to measure?

Comment: It is SGM30C2 which are being used

Comment: It is for technical monitoring only. That sensor is connected to Internet through a 4G modem.... that way, technical people will know, for example, when there is power problem in the line. I have not the information about the maximum current that all houses together might draw.

Comment: Great! We will need to know the maximum current before finalizing solution. But that might be possible to do in the field.

Comment: please read the revised answer. Let me know if you agree with my assumptions, and then make a choice as to whether you can feasibly determine the maximum current you want to measure, (for example via the utility pole transformers, or the number of houses) or whether you wish to choose a test and modify strategy for finding the appropriate CTs.

Comment: Hello...  I was told that at worst case, 11 A will be consumed by houses, but I am wondering why that is imnportant since the circuit with the sensor is independent on the line that goes to the houses due to the existing CT's. They generate a new current proportional to the current going to the houses. Please, take into account that system is currently working without any problems (with schema I shown). The only thing to solve is to allow current measurement. Can you connect to https://cutt.ly/9jRrJRU? That is a store in Chile selling CT's. A turns ratio could be, for example 1:200?

Comment: You said: "The meter does not require a current above 5A, but a current from 0 to 5A.". In practice that is not true. When current is below 5 A, the meter that not measures. Where in the doc you saw that?

Comment: On page 18 of the user guide there is a chart. You have the SGM30C2 model.

Comment: I will ask the electrical engeneer about that. But the practical fact is that the meter does not measure when current is below 5A. The problem is stated very simple, just to amplify current from some mA to at least 5A, but it seems it is no that simple,right? not even using other CT's between the line CT and the meter?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think the meter does not measure when the _line_ current is below 5A, not when the CT current is below 5A. The CT current varies depending upon model, but a standard size is for max CT current to be 5A. Yes, generating a current greater than 5A using an op-amp is  not feasible unless the op-amp is only _part_ of the solution, or one has a specialty op-amp.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about line current and CT current. The fact is that if current entering in current input of the meter should have above 5A. Also, what do you mean with "the op-amp is only part of the solution"? What about placing another CT between the line CT and the meter?

Comment: 1) The line current may be 300A. However, with a 600:5 CT, the output of the CT will be 2.5A.  That 2.5A will be fed into one of the inputs of the SGM30C2. 2) An op amp typically has an output measured in mA, not in A. Therefore, an op amp by itself could not provide the current level you want for your meter. 3) If your meter were not a SGM30C2, but another model, the meter would require the full current to measure. If you want to measure 300A, then 300A needs to be fed to the meter. You could achieve that by either a 600:600 CT, or a 600:5 CT followed by a 5:600 CT (a 600:5 in reverse). But..

Comment: ...But, you don't need to do that because your model meter takes a 0-5A input, not a 0-600A input. It takes as its input the output of a CT.

Comment: I have checked, and as Page 18 shows, 5 (1) means that the range is 1 A to 5 A. Not 0 to 5 as you wrote, Now, please consider this practical case. Line CT ratio is 10:5. It means that if in the line goes 1 A, the meter will be fed with 500 mA, and that current will not be measured. Now, if other CT is placed before the meter input, what CT could you recomend in this case? There are many CT types available.

Comment: I believe that that the 5 (1) means that there is an option to use a 1A CT as an alternative to a 5A CT. 5A and 1A are two standard sizes of CT.

Comment: Remember, I cannot change the CT in the main line. So, if, for example, in the meter line there is 25 mA, it will be goot a CT with ratio of 1:100

Comment: If you cannot change the CT in the main line, then you need to choose a CT which will handle the maximum current that you may expect to see in you mains. So you either need to find out how much the utility pole transformers carry, or know how much current each building is drawing. I do not understand the rest of your comment, about "in the meter linle there is 25mA." If the meter line had only 25mA, and the CT had a ratio of 1:100, then there would only be 2.5A in the main line. At 380V that is less than 1kW. It is unlikely your buildings draw so little, although in some locales it is possible

Comment: By "meter line" I mean the line that inputs the meter, and by "main line" is the line that goes to the houses. The secondary of the CT in the main line has 25 mA, for example.  So if I place a 1:100 CT in the meter line, I willl have 25 mA in its primary and 2.5 A in its secondary. So, 2.5 A will finally enter the meter. That will be feasible to measure by the meter. The greatest question now is about how to close the circuit. I think I could connect all of GND together wih the meter, however, I am not sure about that yet.

Comment: Why do you say that the secondary of the CT has 25mA? Have you already installed CTs there? Do you already know what the current is in the main line? If so, what is the  model of the CTs that are installed, and what is the current in the main line?

Comment: Yes...  I know that the secondary line, in order to call it in some way, pass 25 mA. That 25mA are entering into the meter. As the main picture I uploaded before, there is a CT in the main line. That secondary has 25mA.

Comment: After a lot of discussion, I came to the conclusion that technically is not possible. We will need 18,000 CT for all the secondary lines installed in the country. And even when the CT in the secondary line with a 1:100 ratio is possible, there is no manufacturer capable to build such a quantity. I have not found one yet.

Comment: And in your opinion. Why won't a current amplifier circuit work? would be the problem that the ICs or transistors that would be used will not be able to operate at currents more than 1A? Heat dissipation could be extremely high, I think, if that is the reason.

Comment: Once again, how do you know that the current in the CT secondary is 25mA if you do not know what CT you will be using nor what the current is through the mains line? The current form the CT secondary will depend upon a) why the turns ratio is of the CT, and b) the current in the mains line. But you seem to think you know what the current is anyway. How?

Comment: A current amplifier could work. However, a) the circuit you offer in your question does not take a current input, but a voltage input, and b) the circuit you offer in your question has single sided output, it does not output bi-directional current.

Comment: The information I have received is that the secondary has 25 mA for rural places. I am electronical engineer searching for a way to amplify that current to a current feasible to be measured. That information (25mA) was delivered to me by the electrical engineer who has worked on that implementation (remember, this system is already installed, so I think current was measured in some way). For me it is transparent, the fact is that I should consider that current as a parameter for the problem.

Comment: I have thought about using a power transistor, such as 2N3035, but I have found only information about how it behaves at CC, not AC. On the other hand, power dissipation of it is 115 W according to datasheet so I think I cannot use an element that generates so much heat.

Comment: I started a chat discussion, but didn't see you there, and now it is gone. You do not want to use a transistor, because a transistor only allows current in one direction, and you have current in both directions. Are you still working on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like either the CT is wrong, or the meter is programmed incorrectly, IMO.

What is the part number on the split core transformer that you've purchased?

Unless your CT has taps on the secondary, it comes with a fixed secondary current. That second table should be what is used to create the full part number. SCTK667H-036 is the model, the full part number should be something like: SCTK667H-036 **-200/5**. You would need to specify the rated input current as well as if you want 1A or 5A on the secondary. Sounds like you've received a 1A secondary model.

Have you programmed the meter? The datasheet shows 1 A basic and 5 A maximum. Is there an internal setting that changes the measurement range from 0-1 A to 0-5 A? The meter should've come with both technical specifications and an operating manual. If it didn't, return it and get your money back.

You've got a smart meter here and loads of CT options to choose from. Building a DIY circuit here is foolish and dangerous. Buy the correct equipment for the job. The cost of having an electrical apparatus/circuit approved by regulatory bodies for commercial/residential low voltage applications is going to be 1000x the cost of a new CT.

Comment: No.... CT's and sensors are well programmed and configured. They are being used everywhere in the country. This is only a technical limitation when using such a configuration in places where are a few houses in rural parts. The only solution is to elevate the current so that the sensor can measure.

Comment: Frankly, I disagree that the *only* solution is to implement some secondary circuit. There is a variety of CTs noted above and the meter measurement range starts at 3 mA for the CT connected method (form the specifications). If the power draw in this area is too low, consider using a CT with a smaller measurement window. A 0-5 A output looks different, linearly, for a CT spec'd at 50 A or for one at 600 A. Your actual CT should still have a specific part number. I'd be interested to see a photo of what you actually have on hand.